# Topological definition of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I'm having trouble understanding the topological definition of continuous function.

$f: X \to Y$ is continuous if $V \subseteq Y$ and $V$ open in $Y \implies f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology be $f(x) = \frac{x(x-1)}{x-1}$. From the limit definition we know that $f$ is discontinuous but I can't find an open set that "fall" into a not open set of $\mathbb{R}$.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Are you sure you have defined your function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find any failure of the topological definition, because you have excluded the point of discontinuity from the domain.  That is, your function is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

For each $\require{cancel}x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}$, $f(x)=\frac{x\cancel{(x-1)}}{\cancel{x-1}}=x$, and therefore $f$ is obviously a continuous function.